# Split an array into two subsequence such that the difference between the xor value of the subsequence is the minimum

Tags: bitwise-operators

I am doing some question about bitwise operations. So I am thinking what is the fastest way to find the difference between the xor value(two non-overlapping subesequence that cover the whole array). I couldn't find a fast way to solve this problem. I think this problem will be quite interesting to solve. I hope anyone can come up with a fast solution and share in this post.

I apologize for my bad english :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that we have to split the given array into two subarrays such that difference between xor of elements of one sub array and that of elements of other subarray is minimum.

```
int main() {
int n,*a;
cin>>n;
a = new int[n];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
    cin>>a[i];
}
int total_xor=0;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
    total_xor ^=a[i]; 
}
int min_diff = 1000000009,part_xor=0,split_index=0,i;
for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
    total_xor^=a[i];
    part_xor^=a[i];
    if((abs(total_xor-part_xor))<min_diff) {
        min_diff=abs(total_xor-part_xor);
        split_index = i;
    }
    //cout<<abs(total_xor-part_xor)<<"\n";
}
cout<<"First subarray 1 to "<<split_index+1<<"\n";
cout<<"Second subarray "<<(split_index+2)<<" to "<<n<<"\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If by a subsequence you mean a continuous sub-array, then Sanjeevkumar's answer is sufficient.

However, if you meant that you need to split the array into two arrays, without the condition that they are both formed from continuous ranges, the easiest solution that comes to my mind is by using Dynamic Programming.

your **DP** array would need to have 2 dimensions:

1. `i`: The current index you are trying to choose whether to add to the first or the second subsequence.
2. `firstXOR`: The XOR for all the elements already added to the **first** subsequence.

your **DP** relation is as follows:

`DP[i][firstXOR]` *= min(*`DP[i+1][firstXOR ^ a[i]]`*,* `DP[i+1][firstXOR]`*)*

1. `DP[i+1][firstXOR ^ a[i]]` represents the choice of adding the current element to the first subsequence.
2. `DP[i+1][firstXOR]` represents the choice of adding the current element to the second subsequence.

When you reach the base state (`i == end of the array`) you should return the difference between `firstXOR` and `secondXOR` (`secondXOR` is the XOR of the elements added to the second subsequence).

Note that you can easily obtain `secondXOR` (the XOR of elements you have already added to the second subsequence) by performing the following operation:

`secondXOR` = (XOR of **all** elements in the array) **^** (`firstXOR`)

Comment: I dun really understand can u provide me a pseudo code or a code of any programming language

Comment: tks that really helps :)